# How to use filter in match_all in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

Query is below

```
{
  "from" : 0, 
  "size" : 100,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I need to `filter` from the match_all if `name` is `test`

i tried with

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 100,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": [ "term": { "name": "test" }}]
}
```

I got error 'Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [filter].')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to wrap your query in a bool query , try out this search query:

```
    {
  "from":0,
  "size":10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
           "grocery_name": "elastic"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

According to the comment mentioned by @Nons

**Search Query:**

> Terms query return documents that contain an exact term in a provided
> field.

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
           "parentName.keyword": "Developer"    <-- note this
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64275684",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "A",
          "parentName": "Developer",
          "Data": [
            {
              "id": "455",
              "name": "Google",
              "lastUpdatedDate": "2020-09-10",
              "parent_id": "1"
            }
          ],
          "Function": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "Major"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

> You can even use a match query where the provided text is analyzed
> before matching.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "parentName": "developer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the `match_all` query useful?

Comment: how to apply on `{"from" : 0, "size" : 100,"query": {"match_all": {}}})

`

Comment: @Val I don't know @Nons use case, but the query which he was using above need to be wrapped inside bool query (so that all the documents will be returned using `match all`, and then filter applied to just extract the particular document having `"name:"test"`. And as the filter will not affect the scoring, so search result will have a score = 1.0

Comment: how to pass the size i need to pass the size also

Comment: Ok, it's just a waste of typing because `must/match_all` in this context is irrelevant :-)

Comment: @Nons I have updated my answer, (have included the `from` and `size` parameter). Please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you resolve your issue 

Comment: `[ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'A', 'parentName': 'Developer', 'Data': [ { 'id': '455', 'name': 'Google', 'lastUpdatedDate': '2020-09-10', 'parent_id': '1' } ], 'Function': [ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Major', } ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'B', 'parentName': 'Tester', 'Data': [ { 'id': '455', 'name': 'Google', 'lastUpdatedDate': '2020-09-10', 'parent_id': '2' } ], 'Function': [ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Major', } ] } ]`

Comment: i am searching for `parentName` which is `developer` which is not working

Comment: @Nons please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: can i  give \*Developer\* like this  star for contain search

Comment: Yes @Nons, in the match query you can give `Developer` or `developer`

Comment: no bro stat which means contains also i can do right

Comment: @Nons As far as I can understand your question,  yes you can use, `*Developer*` also, but no need to use wildcard search here, as when you are writing `Developer` in the match query, then it searches for all the documents that contain `Developer` in `parentName`

Comment: in some of the `parentName` is `Developer and Testing` which  need to be extracted . I have tested with `*Developer*`. but now showing zero match

Comment: @Nons I have tested locally with match query like this : `{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "parentName": "*Developer*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}` and the results are showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the Chrome ElasticSearch Head plugin. It allows to test and run searches against Elastic very easily (functionality is similar to MySql Workbech).

Please find example of usage of plugin below (combination of condition and aggregation).

[image]